# hadoop Mapreduce plugin for eclipse not working

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

I built a hadoop mapreduce plugin for hadoop-2.3.0 by using [this](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/47/build-install-configure-eclipse-plugin-apache-hadoop)
and bundle-classpath is

```
Bundle-classpath: classes/, 
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-auth-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-common-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-hdfs-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/protobuf-java-${protobuf.version}.jar,
lib/log4j-${log4j.version}.jar,
lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,
lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar,
lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,
lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar,
lib/commons-collections-${commons-collections.version}.jar,
lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar,
lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar,
lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar,
lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,
lib/guava-${guava.version}.jar,
lib/netty-${netty.version}.jar
```

Build is also successful. I added built jar file hadoop-eclipse-plugin.jar in eclipse\plugins but on opening eclipse ide windows->open perspective->others, there is no perspective for mapreduce. Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou

I am using eclipse-kepler-sr2 package.

Comment: Trying starting Eclipse with the -clean option to rebuild to plugin caches.

Comment: @greg-449 I am trying to connect to hadoop dfs but an internal error is occurring saying "An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater".
org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils". Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you have a new question you should create a new question.